on dismiss() view unable to get update serviceCall in HomeView in SwiftUI
I have HomeView here i am showing favMenu data from favViewModel.fetchFavList. now in HomeView addmore click on i got to FavouriteView here in save button service call i updated the favViewModel.fetchFavList but the same updated favViewModel.fetchFavList is not reflecting in HomeView after dismiss the FavouriteView.. why?? the old list only showing??
HomeView code:
struct HomeView: View {

@StateObject private var favViewModel = FavMenuViewModel()
@State private var favMenu: [AllMenu] = []

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack{
            favView()
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        favViewModel.fetchFavList { status in
            if status{
                favMenu = favViewModel.favMenuList.filter { $0.isSelected == true }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $gotoAddMore) {
        FavouriteView(showSideMenu: $showSideMenu)
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
    }
    @ViewBuilder func favView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                
                ForEach(0..<favMenu.count + 1, id: \.self) { ind in
                    if ind == favMenu.count {
                        Button {
                            gotoAddMore = true
                        } label: {
                            VStack(spacing: 6) {
                                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            }
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    } else {
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            favCell(item: favMenu[ind], index: ind)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

codeFavouriteView: here in updateFavoriteMenus service call success updated favViewModel.fetchFavList and its updated list also showing but in Save button click it got dismiss() then why my updated favViewModel.fetchFavList not showing in HomeView??? please guide after dismiss() of FavouriteView i need updated fetchFavList in HomeView
struct FavouriteView: View {

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@StateObject private var favViewModel = FavMenuViewModel()
@State private var selectedItem: Int = 0
@State var selectedfavMenu: AllMenu? = nil

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        VStack {
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        updateFavoriteMenus()
                        dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Save")
                    })
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<favViewModel.favMenuList.count, id: \.self) { ind in
                        favCell(item: favViewModel.favMenuList[ind], index: ind)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            favViewModel.fetchFavList { status in
                selectedItem = favViewModel.favMenuList.filter({ $0.isSelected}).count
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateFavoriteMenus() {
        //some code
        do {
            if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                print("Response JSON: \(jsonResponse)")
                favViewModel.fetchFavList { status in
                    print("updated fav menus.... \(favViewModel.favMenuList)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func favCell(item: AllMenu, index: Int) -> some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(item.title ?? "")
                .font(.calibriRegular(with: 20))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
            
            Toggle("", isOn: $favViewModel.favMenuList[index].isSelected)
                .labelsHidden()
                .onChange(of: favViewModel.favMenuList[index].isSelected) { isSelected in
                    handleToggleChange(for: item, isSelected: isSelected)
                }
        }
    }
    func handleToggleChange(for item: AllMenu, isSelected: Bool) {
        selectedfavMenu = item
        selectedfavMenu?.isSelected = isSelected
        selectedItem = favViewModel.favMenuList.filter { $0.isSelected }.count
    }
}


You're expecting .onAppear on HomeView get called when dismissing from FavouriteView, right?

@sonle, dismissing from FavouriteView .onAppear is calling in HomeView but giving old data only not updated from FavouriteView... why? but same servicecall prints updated data in FavouriteView

Hmm, how about changing favViewModel in FavouriteView to @Binding and then passing it from HomeView?

Do you self a favor and watch “Demystify SwiftUI” there are so many issues I don’t even know where to start.

You have multiple @StateObject private var favViewModel = FavMenuViewModel(). You must have only
one source of truth, one such declaration (in HomeView). You then pass down that model to the other views (FavouriteView).
See  Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app. Note also, do not use such ForEach(0..<favViewModel.favMenuList.count it is bad programming.

State should always be private

You're going to run into major issues if you try to use StateObject for view models, use View structs as the view model
